# Read in the first 4 digits of a line in a file and store it

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to read in the first 4 digits in a `.dat` file and store it in a loop for every line. The `.dat` file looks like this:

```
0004 | IP
0006 | IP
0008 | IP
```

I want to create a loop that reads in the first four digits and stores is for that iteration of the loop until its read the whole file and then writes it to an out put file.

I wrote this, but all it does is basically convert the .dat to a csv

```
with open('stores.dat', 'r') as input_file:
    lines = input_file.readlines()
    newLines = []
    for line in lines:
        newLine = line.strip('|').split()
        newLines.append(newLine)


with open('file.csv', 'w') as output_file:
    file_writer = csv.writer(output_file)
    file_writer.writerows(newLines)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `newLine = line.split()[0]`? You can also specify a max split limit of `1` to speed up in case the lines are long or get the first four characters by `newLine = line[:4]`

Comment: @dcg that is not correct as well. `line.strip('|')` does not do anything here. What OP needs is `newLine = line.split('|')[0]`, or simply `newLine = line[:4]` if there're always 4 digits before `|`

Comment: @JoYSword That's what I mean. I didn't see the `strip` call. I fix my comment. Thanks

Comment: @JoYSword i did that but adds a comma between each digit, any way to correct that?

Comment: @krazekidg Are you trying to add a comma between each digit, or did you do so (and not want to)?

Comment: @JoYSword no I'm not trying to add a comma between each digits, i Just want 0004 to be 0004 for newLine

Comment: @krazekidg each element of your newLines will be a line. For a line in a csv, it needs to be a list. If it is a string, it will be split to characters. So what you need is `newLines.append([newLine])` in your first `for` loop.

Comment: Why write with `csv.writer` when there is only 1 item per line? Why not just `write`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know you want to read 4 characters every time, you can just read a slice:

```py
import csv

# you can open multiple file handles at the same time
with open('stores.dat', 'r') as input_file, \
     open('file.csv', 'w') as output_file:
    file_writer = csv.writer(output_file)
    # iterate over the file handle directly to get the lines
    for line in input_file:
        row = line[:4] # slice the first 4 chars
        # make sure this is wrapped as a list otherwise
        # you'll get unsightly commas in your rows
        file_writer.writerow([row])
```

Which outputs

```sh
$ cat file.csv
0004
0006
0008
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have always four digits starting every line it is as simple as

```
with open('stores.dat', 'r') as input_file:
               lines = input_file.readlines()
               newLines = []
               for line in lines:
                  newLine = line[:4]
                  newLines.append(newLine)
```

Otherwise, you could use a regex to do the job, as such:

```
import re

with open('stores.dat', 'r') as input_file:
               lines = input_file.readlines()
               newLines = []
               for line in lines:
                  newLine = re.findall(r'\d{3}', line)[0]
                  newLines.append(newLine)
```

Note that `re.findall()` will return a `list` with all the matches for that line, hence the `[0]` at the end, for returning only the first match, or the first element of the list.